# Viewing the date_column with different hours in a table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mariadb, recursive-query

[image]

I have a table called shift where I want to view  the sdate column  with the date followed by the start_time of the shift. Essentially, I am trying to split this sdate for  managers LB1 and AE1 into 6 records each by adding the start_time of the shift. For eg.
`2017-08-12 08:00, 2017-08-12  09:00, 2017-08-12   10:00` for manager LB1. The same has to be done for manager AE1 Is there a way this table can be viewed this way without altering it?

Comment: Can you add the desired output for this test case? Should it be 6 separate rows for each manager? Why 6? For each hour?

Comment: What is your version of MySql? Also why 5 rows for AE1?

Comment: @forpas I have corrected that. It should be 6 for each.I am solving this problem on sqlzoo.net so don't know which version its running.

Comment: You can execute `select version();` to get the version.

Comment: @RusArtM Yes, Its 6 separate rows for each manager 1 for every new hour.

Comment: @forpas This is what the query returned -10.3.18-MariaDB-0+deb10u1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a recursive cte that returns all the hours from `00:00` to `23:00` and join to the table:

```
with recursive cte as (
  select '00:00' time
  union all
  select concat(lpad(time + 1, 2, '0'), ':00') from cte
  where time + 0 < 23
)
select t.*, c.time 
from tablename t inner join cte c
on c.time >= t.start_time and c.time < t.end_time
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3999cc0eaab7c2cd4cc2c21e30641396).
Results:

```
> Manager | sdate      | start_time | end_time | difference | time 
> :------ | :--------- | :--------- | :------- | ---------: | :----
> LB1     | 2017-08-12 | 08:00      | 14:00    |          6 | 08:00
> LB1     | 2017-08-12 | 08:00      | 14:00    |          6 | 09:00
> LB1     | 2017-08-12 | 08:00      | 14:00    |          6 | 10:00
> LB1     | 2017-08-12 | 08:00      | 14:00    |          6 | 11:00
> LB1     | 2017-08-12 | 08:00      | 14:00    |          6 | 12:00
> LB1     | 2017-08-12 | 08:00      | 14:00    |          6 | 13:00
> AE1     | 2017-08-12 | 14:00      | 20:00    |          6 | 14:00
> AE1     | 2017-08-12 | 14:00      | 20:00    |          6 | 15:00
> AE1     | 2017-08-12 | 14:00      | 20:00    |          6 | 16:00
> AE1     | 2017-08-12 | 14:00      | 20:00    |          6 | 17:00
> AE1     | 2017-08-12 | 14:00      | 20:00    |          6 | 18:00
> AE1     | 2017-08-12 | 14:00      | 20:00    |          6 | 19:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [recursive common table expression](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/), available in Maria DB since version 10.2.2:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select manager, sdate, start_time, end_time 
    from mytable
    union all
    select managear, sdate, start_time + interval 1 hour, end_time 
    from cte 
    where start_time < end_time - interval 1 hour
)
select manager, sdate, start_time, start_time + interval 1 hour end_time from cte
```